# Improper output while filtering a hashmap

Tags: java

I have a hashmap which has key and value in String. The data is in the form of `(table1, "table1:ssn1,ssn2,ssn3")`. The table name in key is of the source table name and table name in the value is of the destination table name along with the corresponding source systems names separated by a ":".
I am trying to pass source system names in arguments from the command line to filter out the key and value along with the received source system name.
I came up with the following code so far:

```
public class FilterKeyValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] valArr;
        String ky;
        Map<String, String> hmap     = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> filtered = new HashMap<String, String>();

        hmap.put("Table1", "Table1:SSN1,SSN2,SSN3,SSN4,SSN5");
        hmap.put("Table2", "Table2:SSN1,SSN4,SSN2,SSN5,SSN8,SSN9,SSN10");
        hmap.put("Table3", "Table3:SSN4,SSN1");
        hmap.put("Table4", "Table4:SSN5,SSN6,SSN7");
        hmap.put("Table5", "Table5:SSN8,SSN1,SSN5,SSN2");

        if(args.length > 0) {
            for(String ssname: args) {
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : hmap.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getValue().contains(ssname)) {
                        ky      = entry.getKey();
                        valArr  = entry.getValue().split(":");
                        filtered.put(ky, valArr[0]+":"+ssname);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (String iter: filtered.keySet()){
            String key = iter.toString();
            String value = filtered.get(key).toString();  
            System.out.println(key + "->" + value);
        }

    }
}
```

In the arguments, I am passing: SSN1 SSN2 in the arguments. The output should be

```
Table1->Table1:SSN1
Table2->Table2:SSN1
Table3->Table3:SSN1
Table5->Table5:SSN1
Table1->Table1:SSN2
Table2->Table2:SSN2
Table5->Table5:SSN2
```

Instead, I am getting the output of:

```
Table2->Table2:SSN2
Table3->Table3:SSN1
Table5->Table5:SSN2
Table1->Table1:SSN2
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: as you have used map for filtered data, map will not allow duplicate keys.. that is the reason data is getting overridden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to put multiple values into a `Map` using the same key. For each key, a map can only ever hold one value.

Therefore, only the last value that you add for any given key will be visible in the end.

Generally speaking your code suggests that Strings are not the correct data type for your data and that you should be storing it in a more structured form (such as a `Map<String,List<String>>`).

Comment: Is there a way to pass the output to two separate Hashmaps dynamically ? i.e. if I have 2 arguments, I should have 2 hashmaps accordingly. Is it possible ?

Comment: It's certainly possible to produce a list of hashmaps or even a hashmap of hashmaps. I'm unsure if it helps solve your problem, though, because it's not entirely clear what you're trying to solve. For example, simply replacing the `filtered.put` with the appropriate `System.out.println` would make your code "work", but I'm not sure that that's what you want.

Comment: Ok. As of now, using the table names in Key and Values, and source system names in the Value, I am calculating the count of records in the both source and destination tables. But I got a requirement of doing it for source system names received from command line. Hence I am trying to filter the main hashmap to get the table names related to the arguments received in a new hashmap in the same format as the main hashmap.

Comment: I am trying to do this as I can just send this filtered collection to same method which calculates the counts of source and destination tables without changing any code in it. Hope this gave an idea.

Answer (score 0):

As i have observed, key is included in value.. so you can use a simple arraylist fro targeted data.. this may help you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] valArr;
        String ky;
        Map<String, String> hmap     = new HashMap<String, String>();
        List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<String>();

        hmap.put("Table1", "Table1:SSN1,SSN2,SSN3,SSN4,SSN5");
        hmap.put("Table2", "Table2:SSN1,SSN4,SSN2,SSN5,SSN8,SSN9,SSN10");
        hmap.put("Table3", "Table3:SSN4,SSN1");
        hmap.put("Table4", "Table4:SSN5,SSN6,SSN7");
        hmap.put("Table5", "Table5:SSN8,SSN1,SSN5,SSN2");

        if(args.length > 0) {
            for(String ssname: args) {
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : hmap.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getValue().contains(ssname)) {
                        ky      = entry.getKey();
                        valArr  = entry.getValue().split(":");
                        filtered.add(valArr[0]+":"+ssname);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (String iter: filtered){
            System.out.println(iter.split(":")[0]+ "->" + iter);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the items:

```
valArr  = entry.getValue().substring(entry.getValue().indexOf(":")).split(",");
```

Here is complete code which produces the output you desire:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] valArr;
    String ky;
    Map<String, String> hmap     = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> filtered = new HashMap<String, String>();

    hmap.put("Table1", "Table1:SSN1,SSN2,SSN3,SSN4,SSN5");
    hmap.put("Table2", "Table2:SSN1,SSN4,SSN2,SSN5,SSN8,SSN9,SSN10");
    hmap.put("Table3", "Table3:SSN4,SSN1");
    hmap.put("Table4", "Table4:SSN5,SSN6,SSN7");
    hmap.put("Table5", "Table5:SSN8,SSN1,SSN5,SSN2");

    if(args.length > 0) {
        for(String ssname: args) {
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : hmap.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().contains(ssname)) {
                    ky      = entry.getKey();
                    valArr  = entry.getValue().substring(entry.getValue().indexOf(":")).split(",");
                    for (String val : valArr) {
                        if (val.equals(ssname)) {
                            filtered.put(ky, ky+":"+ssname);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (String iter: filtered.keySet()){
        String key = iter.toString();
        String value = filtered.get(key).toString();  
        System.out.println(key + "->" + value);
    }

}
```